# how to find a date earlier than the oldest one in another column; in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two dates columns date1 and date2 and I would like to take only ids that have date1 earlier than the oldest date in date2 for each id, as date1<= min(date2). For instance:

```
ID :::    Date1 :::      Date2
ID_1 :::  2010-01-01 :::  2010-04-03 
ID_1 :::  2010-03-02 :::  2010-04-03 
ID_1 ::: 2007-05-04 ::: 2008-04-05  <--- I would this
```

I get an aggregation problem.
I should add date1 to the clause group by, but I get result that I don't want. How can I fix this problem? In the final code, that I have reported below, I would the ID and the repeated measures done in Date1, that was done before the oldest Date2 for that ID. Thanks in advance

```
SELECT  ID, count(Date1)
FROM myTable
where (field like '%hi%')
group by ID, Date1
having (count(Date1) <= 500
    and Date1 <= min(Date2))
order by ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the original rows, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(date2) over (partition by id) as min_date2
      from mytable t
     ) t
where date1 < min_date2;
```

If you want only ids, then you are saying the `min(date1) < min(date2)`, so aggregation is sufficient:

```
select id
from mytable
group by id
having min(date1) < min(date2);
```

And, if you want to, you can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.date1 < (select min(t2.date) from mytable t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: I'll use definitely the first code that you provided me. It works better for my goal. Thank you very much